# Pandas, by row calculations with the first value that satisfy condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [10,20,40],
        [2,1,26],
        [1, 2, 60],
    ], columns = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
)

df['cumsum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['cumsum_perc'] = (df['cumsum'] * 0.1).astype(int)


|    |   f1 |   f2 |   f3 |   cumsum |   cumsum_perc |
|---:|-----:|-----:|-----:|---------:|--------------:|
|  0 |   10 |   20 |   40 |       70 |             7 |
|  1 |    2 |    1 |   26 |       29 |             2 |
|  2 |    1 |    2 |   60 |       63 |             6 |
```

As you can see, for each row I have calculated cumulative sum, and than out of cumulative sum an arbitrary (in this case 10%) percentage of the cumulative sum.

Each f column has its ponder value (f_pon), f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3 = 3.

Now, for each row, I have to find out f column with highest value, whose value is less or equal then cumsum_perc (f_le) in order to determine its f_pon.

Let's consider the third row, for an example.

f_le = f2 (2 < 6), which implies f_pon = 2.

Now I have to see is there any reminder in cumsum_perc - f_le column.
rem = cumsum_perc (6) - f_le (2) = 4.

I have to calculate percentage of reminder considering the value of the first f column to the right of f_le (f3), so here we have rem_perc = rem (4) / f3 (60) = 0.066.

Final result for the third row is f_pon (2) + rem_perc = 2.066.

If we apply the same logic for the first row, than f1 is f_le, and there is no reminder because cumsum_perc (7) - f_le (10) = -3. If rem is negative it should be set to 0.
So result is f1_pon (1) + rem (0) / f2 (20) = 1

For second row, the result is also 1, because there is no reminder.

How to calculate final results for each row in the most efficient way?

Comment: `I have to find out f column with highest value, whose value is less or equal then cumsum_perc` for row0 no column fits but you picked one anyway? is it random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it is difficult to follow your rules, but since you now your rules, I suggest to implement a helper function and use `df.apply(helper, axis=1)` row wise.

This might not be the fastest implementation, but at least you get you results.

```
def helper(x):
    basic_set = x[['f1','f2','f3']]
    cumsum_perc = x['cumsum_perc']
    f_pon  = basic_set[basic_set<cumsum_perc].max()
    rem = cumsum_perc - f_pon
    if not rem:
        rem = 0
    rem_perc = rem / x['cumsum']
    if not rem_perc:
        rem_perc = 0
    return f_pon + rem_perc
df['ans'] = df.apply(helper, axis=1)

>>> df
   f1  f2  f3  cumsum  cumsum_perc       ans
0  10  20  40      70            7       NaN
1   2   1  26      29            2  1.034483
2   1   2  60      63            6  2.063492
```

I think you can adapt the `helper`, if mine is wrong.